# Error message when reading subdirectory from a USB Drive

Tags: files, usb-drive, disk

When attempting to display a directory (sorry, I'm strictly GUI for now because I'm new to this) I get the following error for a folder that reads flawlessly when attached to various Windows boxes.

This location could not be displayed.

Sorry, could not display all the contents of “diskname”: Error when getting information for file '/media/abc/etcetc/Personal Folders/IMG_0035.JPG': Input/output error

I am willing to toss the file to see if it resolves but I don't know how to do that yet. I am going to get the appropriate terminal script and get to work on that but I thought I would ask here in the meantime.

Is there some way to find out why it hangs on the one file?

What is the easiest way to toss the file?

UPDATE:

After trying to change the settings to suppress thumbnails (thanks user3121023) and using newly learned commands in the terminal, I am still stuck. The command line returned the same error.

I will mount the drive on a Windows box later and try to see if I can resolve it there. I should at least be able to remove the file.

Comment: You might go into preferences for the GUI you are using to view the contents of the drive and disable preview or thumbnails. I am using 13.10 and preferences are under File.

Comment: No, it still fails but thanks for showing me another place to play around!

Comment: You should be able to delete the file with `rm "/media/abc/etcetc/Personal Folders/IMG_0035.JPG"`. Since there is a space between Personal and Folders, you will need to put quotes(") around the path. Run that command from a terminal. You can start a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+t on the keyboard.

Comment: Yes I did that (I'm learning) and got essentially the same error message in the command line. Then I moved the drive to a Windows box and it had problems too. Then I found out that the drive had been dropped recently... I am now in recovery mode and I will update the thread. I will close this Question though because it is not a Ubuntu issue at all. Thanks for your attention to this matter.

Answer (score 1):

[Solved] The problem it turns out is that the drive has new issues, possibly due to being dropped just prior to connecting it to the Ubuntu computer.